# Determine process for outbound packets

Tags: python, windows, network-programming

Is there a way to determine which process is sending a particular packet. I am capturing packets on Network Interface card and want to determine the process for each packet. I am working in python under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Until you don't implement your own packet filter driver you can't do that just looking on a data stream captured via network card promiscuous mode.

Comment: Well, can I extract the list of running processes on the system and extract information about each processes, and see which port it is holding. This is somewhat similar to netstat command in windows, but I want to do this with python.

Comment: Theoretically you can do this but practically it will mean that you have to rescan open file handlers per process very often because there is any guarantee that some process didnt release a port which being took over by another process.